# Husky error on precommit: npm ERR! missing script: pre-commit

Tags: javascript, json, npm, husky, yarnpkg-v2

I am using latest version of yarn. I am trying to set up Husky in my project.

File `.huskyrc.json`:

```json
{
  "hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
    "pre-push": "npm run test:noWatch"
  }
}
```

File `lintstagedrc.json`

```json
{
  "src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}": ["yarn lint"],
  "*.json": ["prettier --write"]
}
```

File `package.json`

```json
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx,.json --max-warnings 0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx,.json --fix",
    "prettier-format": "prettier --config .prettierrc '**/*.{json,js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,scss,md}' --write"
  },
...
{
```

Error:

```
npm ERR! missing script: pre-commit
```

If I add this to the scripts on `package.json`:

```
"pre-commit": "yarn prettier-format && yarn lint",
```

Then it runs those 2 commands, but what about the configurations on all of those other files? I mean, if I run the pre-commit script, it only runs those prettier-format and yarn lint commands, but the resto of them?

This what I read https://javascript.plainenglish.io/husky-lint-staged-on-a-react-typescript-project-automate-validation-before-submitting-your-code-8d388e63be70 but he never mentioned about the pre-commit script.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry. I didn't know what happened until I saw another project of mine and forgot to add this simple line to `package.json`:

```
{
...
  scripts: {
     "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
  }
...
}
```

Comment: For me it was "precommit" without the dash "-"